# New to JavaScript: Can I pass a List into this function and have it still work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, function

As the title says, I'm new to JavaScript and not completely sure on certain syntax's.

After looking for a while I found the following function:

```
function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
```

All I need to know is if I pass a List of Strings into the functions parameter, will it still work, or when it says array is that defining what kind of variable it is? If it won't currently work with a List what needs to change?

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work.  I am not entirely sure what you mean by "List of Strings"

Comment: You need to know if it works... Why not just try it? Also, there's no such thing as a `List` type in plain JavaScript...

Comment: What exactly are you calling a *list of strings*? JavaScript has arrays, not lists (well, there are "array-like objects", but they're not lists either). List elements (`<dl>`, `<ol>` and `<ul>`) are different beasts entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any **Array** or **Array-like object** containing string items, no matter how the parameter is named, and your function will work as expected.

**Array-like object** is an object, that has a `length` property with *value >=0* and properties *0..length-1*. Array-like object offen does **not** implement Array methods. The Array can be distinguished from Array-like object using `a instanceof Array` or `Array.isArray(a)`, while the `typeof a` returns `'object'` in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

> when it says array is that defining what kind of variable it is?

No. It is defining the name of the variable that the argument will be assigned to in the scope of the function.

JavaScript (at least ES5 which you are using here) doesn't have any type enforcement for function arguments, so you can pass whatever values you like.

The function does expect the value you pass to be an object with a `length` property and a number of properties with names that are integers (i.e. it expects the value to be *like* an array (see also [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing))).

List is not a standard JavaScript data type. If you have created a List object, then you can pass it so long as it is array-like.

Answer (score 1):

`array`is just the name of the expected parameter.
It can be of any type (Javascript doesn't have types)

So: Yes, your list will still "work" (as long as it supports the functions that are called on it, of course)

Answer (score 0):

It will still work. Truly speaking in javascript there is an array no list as such. Hence even if you call the function with below arguments:

```
makeUL(["Cpp","Java","Javascript"])
```

The output would be :

```
<ul>
  <li>Cpp</li>
  <li>Java</li>
  <li>Javascript</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean Array. but i think your function is just returning a DOM element, so you wont directly see that in browser unless you append it into DOM tree.

```
var listofstrings = ['item 1','item 2','item 3'];
document.getElementByName('body').appendChild(makeUL(listofstring));
```